# Any way to run DLL's at button click C#

Tags: c#, interop

I'm looking for ways to speed my program to the max and one way I thought of was to strip all DLL's being run at startup and run them when they need to be.

As an example, I have a DLL containing info required for an update module, but I don't want to  have that running in the program if I don't need it till I have an update. (I know I can create a separate program and link it to that but this is just an example.)

Is there anyway to attach this on a button click?

Sorry if I haven't made my question understandable.

Thanks

Comment: If you're trying to optimize, this is the place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already doing this.

The .Net runtime only loads DLLs as they're needed.
Your update module will only be loaded the first time a method that uses it is JITted.

Comment: O ok thanks for the info. Guess I have to look for other ways to speed up my program